# something wrong with if-else statement in my usecase

Tags: python

I tried to check whether a word contain in a string and then perform later functions but it went into the wrong "if".

```
a = "3,977"

if "割" or "分" in a:
    print("yes")
elif "," in a:
    print(",")
else:
    print("none")
```

current result:

```
"yes"
```

expected result:

```
","
```

Comment: This isn't an exact match to the suggested dupe, but it's close enough IMO. Both turn on the meaning of `'foo' or 'bar'` when compared against something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if "割" or "分" in a:
```

into

```
if "割" in a or "分" in a:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = "3,977"

if any(s in a for s in "割分"):
    print("yes")
elif "," in a:
    print(",")
else:
    print("none")
```